# Phone call recording for instant analysis

Tags: android

Is it possible to record the other party's audio channel during a phonecall? We have a health tech product that analyzes voice for certain conditions and it should only analyze the patient's voice.
I have tried using apps such as Rev that can record calls but our app will need to record only the counterpart's audio stream.